# Why did the Ubuntu GNOME logo change in 15.10?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, design, logo, history-of-ubuntu

Why did the Ubuntu GNOME logo change in 15.10?

15.04: [image] 15.10: [image]

(Logos extracted from the [`plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo) packages of the respective versions.)

Answer (score 12):

There was some discussion on the Ubuntu GNOME mailing lists about [somebody selling Ubuntu GNOME for $30](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-gnome/2015-June/003094.html). One of the follow-up emails was from Patrik Bubák, an Ubuntu GNOME dev, who said:

> As far as the logo is concerned, borrowing GNOME's was a mistake from
>   day 1. It's highly confusing, and due to its complexity difficult to
>   work with, plus using someone else's logo as our own isn't quite all
>   right, even though certain permissions have been given it will never
>   be clear unless it's completely changed, which it will, soon.

Related:

- [Page on Behance.net by Patrik showcasing the new logo](https://www.behance.net/gallery/25233455/Ubuntu-GNOME-new-logo-concept-%28preview%29)
- [Announcement of the new artwork on the mailing lists](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-gnome/2015-April/002976.html)