# What does the new logo of Ubuntu GNOME mean?

Tags: gnome, release-management, design

The new release of Ubuntu GNOME brings a new logo. What does this logo mean? And what is the mainly reason for changing it?

[image]

Comment: The logo will stay since it will be the "new brand identity" of Ubuntu GNOME.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/711474/ .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This one?

[image]

The new logo is a combination of the letters U and G.

I found a topic on the [ubuntu gnome artwork mailing list](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntugnome-artwork/msg00463.html) pointing to [the project page:](https://www.behance.net/gallery/25233455/Ubuntu-GNOME-new-logo-concept-(preview))

1. the shape forms “uG”, thus Ubuntu GNOME
2. “u” is the front liner of the branding in the Ubuntu family font and of the official brand; in a philosophical approach a pointer towards humanity (as in unity)
3. the symbol itself, comprised of two pieces formed together, expresses the same idea
4. both symbols are closely related, placed, and in their union accomplish their purpose of expressing both the philosophical and material aspects of unity via Gestalt

Comment: and there i was thinking it was two lego people hands holding each other :*(

Comment: Where's the ‘G’? I see two ‘U’s, and an ‘S’ or a ‘5’ in the negative space between them.

Comment: @Anko The top "U" is an upper-case "G". Kinda. Slightly. OK, not very much.

Comment: @anko the U is the bottom one and you look at a slight angle at it (turn it 1/4th clockwise). The G is at the top and also at an angle (turn it 2/4th clockwise).