# Changed logo in system information

Tags: system-settings, system-info

I don't know how this happened but the Ubuntu logo has been replaced by this one on the picture. I don't recognise this logo (I haven't looked it up).

How can logo of my distribution change all of the sudden ? Can
it be changed back ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the Ubuntu Gnome logo to me:

[What does the new logo of Ubuntu GNOME mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712057/what-does-the-new-logo-of-ubuntu-gnome-mean)

Maybe you installed Ubuntu Gnome on the side?  Not sure how to put it back, but removing the packages may help.

Comment: Ohh ... I knew about Gnome just wasn't familiar with its logo. I must've downloaded some of its packages then.

Comment: Do you know by any chance which package is responsible for that ? I've been unable to determine what should I get rid of to have it as it was before.

Comment: @MarkAlexa I couldn't say for sure, but google synaptic package manager and that tool should let you search for "gnome".  If it was me, I'd either leave it or reinstall - unless you have a bunch of time to research it, you may spend more time fixing it than reinstalling.